# find an element with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have this table wrote in html with php and bootstrap:

```
<table id="tabela-resultado" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Ativo</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <?php if(count($records)) { ?>
                    <?php foreach($records as $record) { ?> 


                        <tr data-id="<?php echo $record->id; ?>">

                            <td><?php echo $record->nome; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php 

                                    if ($record->ativo == 1) {
                                        echo "SIM"; 
                                    } else if($record->ativo == 0){
                                        echo "NÂO"; 
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo anchor("gurpoProduto/excluir", "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Exlcuir", ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block', 'name' => 'delete']); ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php
                        }
                      }
                    ?>


                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

i'm trying to found an element in the first column using this function with jquery. Tihs is the function:

```
function verificar_existencia(nome) {

        var table = $("#tabela-resultado tbody");
        var nomeTabela = '';

        table.find('tr').each(function (nome) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            nomeTabela = $tds.eq(0).text()


        });

        if(trim(nome.toUpperCase()) === trim(nomeTabela.toUpperCase())) { 

                toastr.success("This element already exists!!!", "Aviso");
                //return false; 
        }   
    }
```

but doesnt work.Whats is wrong? I need find an element in the table to prevent duplicate elements in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through all the rows and overwriting `nomeTabela` every iteration.

Thus once loop completes it is the value found in last row only and that is what your comparison is done on

Do a check inside the loop for each value on each row something like:

```
function verificar_existencia(nome) {
    nome = nome.trim().toUpperCase();

    var table = $("#tabela-resultado tbody");
    var isMatch = false;


    table.find('tr').each(function(nome) {
      var $tds = $(this).find('td');
      var nomeTabela = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
      // compare each value inside the loop
      if (nome === nomeTabela.trim().toUpperCase()) {
        isMatch = true;
        return false; /// break the loop when match found
      }

    });

    if (isMatch) {

      toastr.success("This element already exists!!!", "Aviso");
      //return false; 
    }

}
```

Also note your incorrect use of [`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) which should show up as error in your browser console

Comment: See after `var $tds`?  It is ended with `,`. Try replace it with `;` instead.

Comment: try with typo fixed

Comment: works fine... but the param loop function it's not necessary.. i removed and  works fine.. .please edit... thanks

Comment: remove `nome` param in the loop function

Comment: that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to identify a dupe strings in the first column of the table.

```js
var $trs = $("table tr"), dupes = [];

function san(str) {
  return str.text().trim().toUpperCase();
}

$trs.each(function() {
  var origTd = $(this).find("td:first"), origTr = $(this);
  $trs.each(function() {
    var newTd = $(this).find("td:first"),
      newTr = $(this),
      origTrIdx = origTr.index(),
      newTrIdx = newTr.index(),
      origTdStr = san(origTd),
      newTdStr = san(newTd);
    if (
      origTrIdx > newTrIdx &&
      dupes.indexOf(origTdStr) < 0 &&
      origTdStr === newTdStr
    ) {
      dupes.push(origTdStr);
      console.log(
        'This element "' +
          origTd.text() +
          '" already exists!!!'
      );
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>unique</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>unique2</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>unique2</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>unique2</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```